# Is it possible to do "runtime" routing/switching of current paths?

Tags: switches, driver

I am designing a project involving 12 DC motors, only one of which
will run at any time. I will be using a high-current-capable H-bridge
driver (like [this one](https://www.pololu.com/product/2992)), in
order to run them bidirectionally.

In view of cost minimization, I'd like to use only one driver for the
entire board, i.e., run the motors sequentially by driving one for N
seconds, then moving to the next one, and so on (switching speed/delays are not important at all).

Is it possible to design a low BOM-cost modification (< $5 ideally, for switching between 12 motors) to the circuit where I can runtime-switch
the driver outputs, i.e., programmatically have the driver jump from serving one motor to the next?

I understand that solutions like crossbar/crosspoint ICs as well as
FPGAs are traditionally used to facilitate on-the-fly routing of
digital signals, but what about high-current lines (in this case, 3-4
amps of current draw)?

Comment: Relays. One per motor, energise one relay at a time. (If you're driving the motor both ways from an H bridge, you probably want double pole relays).

Comment: I don't see the need for a double pole relay? One side of each motor is permanently connected to one half-H, the other side of one and only one motor is connected to the other half-H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BOM of $5 is rather low: $5/12 leaves only 42 cents per relay for the simplest solution. (One side of each motor is permanently connected to one half-H, the other side of one and only one motor is connected to the other half-H.)

4 4-throw double pole relays could be used in a tree, which would give you a budget of 84 cents, but now for a 4-pole double-throw relay.

Maybe you have cheaper sources than I have?

Comment: Don't forget to add flyback diodes across the motor terminals. If not already present, these will eat into the budget.

Comment: I don't see an need for extra diodes: the flyback diodes had to be present in the original one-motor circuit, *at the half-H-bridge centres*. The relays are only used for zero-current switching.

Comment: I agree, but I'm still mentioning it in case the OP doesn't know and it would then need to be part of the budget. I don't see anything in the motor driver description that mentions diodes.

Comment: They are intrinsic to the MOSFETs. External diodes just lowers dissipation in the MOSFETs during freewheeling.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect one leg of all the motors to one half of the bridge and switch the other leg using cheaper (than the H-bridge PCB) relays.

It would be a huge pain to use MOSFETs to switch that in a custom solution, and typically you would just dedicate one H-bridge per motor.

With dedicated H-bridges, you can use your knowledge of digital multiplexing to control them easily.

Comment: Would you recommend the relay method given a target BOM cost of < $5 for the modification, in manufacturing quantities?

Comment: I would say that is an unreasonable goal considering what you want.